# Creating LP position via SafeWallet App for multisig. (GS013 Error)

Tags: safe-core

We have successfully created an LP position before using Safe.

Upon trying to interact with the Uniswap app once more, we continually get "GS013" error. We have tried cranking gas and continues to fail repeatedly. Any suggestions?

Last fail; https://etherscan.io/tx/0x004b6f50d96acf5791fda7749a45bada27107e11006e4c56f863965a37c7cb11

Answer (score 0):

When analysing the transaction on [tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x004b6f50d96acf5791fda7749a45bada27107e11006e4c56f863965a37c7cb11?trace=0.1.7.0.0.2), we can see that the actual error is `Transaction too old`. This comes from Uniswap, which has a time limit on each transaction; the error you see (`GS013`) is simply how this error manifests in Safe.

Hope it helps; Best, Louis